# Como melhorar a qualidade da imagem salva?

Tags: javascript, imagem, html2canvas

Utilizo a ferramenta [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) em um projeto para imprimimir uma determinada área do meu código e salvá-la como imagem.

Tentei salvar nos seguintes formatos, *JPEG* e *PNG*, mas ambas ficam com a mesma qualidade, gostaria de saber, de alguém que utiliza esta ferramenta também, se há alguma forma de determinar a qualidade da imagem à ser salva.

#### [EDIT]

Respondendo às questões solicitadas:

1. A tela não é retina
2. O Sistema Operacional é Ubuntu 15.04 x64
3. O navegador é Google Chrome x64

Este é o código de chamada à *html2canvas*, bem simples, praticamente transforma a imagem em *url* salva em um *input* *hidden* para salvá-la com o *PHP* (não sei exatamente se esse envio para salvar com o *PHP* tem algo a ver com este *bug*, caso haja, me avise, por favor):

```
html2canvas($("#result"), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        img = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");

        $("#screenshot").val(img);

        $("#form").submit();
    }
});
```

Neste sistema no qual trabalho, uma de suas funções é criar imagens para postagem no Facebook.

#### O HTML usado consiste em:

Teste
            
            Teste subtítulo

A razão pela qual não utilizo uma imagem de background na `<div id="backgroud">` foi uma decisão relacionada à outras funcionalidades do sistema.

#### O CSS consiste em:

```
div#template {
  width: 500px;
  height: 450px;
  position: relative;  
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
div#background {
  width: 500px;
  height: 450px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
img#bg-image {
  display: none;
}
div#content {
  width: 500px;
  height: 125px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  color: #fff;
  display: table;
  z-index: 2;
}
div#content-bar {
  width: 500px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  backgrund:#000;
}
h1.title {
  color: inherit;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 15px auto;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
h2.subtitle {
  color: inherit;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 75px auto;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

É bem básico, porque, neste caso, só faz o posicionamento *absolute* das *divs* e as posiciona uma sobre a outra, deixando a `<div id="background">` por trás, tendo função de plano de fundo.

#### Uma imagem de exemplo

Não sei se vai dar pra ver muito bem, mas estou enviando um print que tirei de uma imagem postada depois de pronta.

Se perceber, a imagem está um pouco "borrada", durante a construção da imagem isso não ocorre.

[image: Imagem postada]

Não postei o HTML e CSS relacionados à imagem, pois não tenho eles à minha disposição no momento.

Comment: Nesse caso, para manter a qualidade, não seria melhor tentar converter o print em svg?

Comment: Também pensei nisto, mas ainda não tentei, tentarei.

Comment: Se você possuir a imagem em Canvas, você pode converte-la em SVG utilizando esse plug-in: https://github.com/gliffy/canvas2svg

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio o problema é que aí já foi gerado com baixa qualidade.

Comment: Então @bigown, estava a comentar isso, o ideal seria converter direto do HTML pro SVG, so que nunca precisei fazer algo do tipo, vou dar uma pesquisada, se achar alguma solução, posto aqui

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio Se você se refere ao `foreignObject`, acho que ele é bloqueado no Chrome por "segurança".

Comment: Poste o html e css também, se possivel poste uma imagem do problema.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento postado :)

Comment: @ThomersonRoncally Não entendi a parte do facebook na foto. Faz assim, sem querer pedir demais rs, posta um exemplo completo no jsfiddle por favor.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Ok rsrs

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Editado rsrs JSFiddle + PHP + Imagem

Comment: O teste que eu fiz não houve perda de qualidade, veja o resultado: http://i.stack.imgur.com/u2EzW.jpg - pra mim parece "perfeita". Depois eu testei com cores mais avermelhadas (http://www.socwall.com/images/wallpapers/26794-1920x1200.jpg) e o resultado foi este: http://i.stack.imgur.com/5uQ5s.jpg - Com cores mais quentes é possivel observar mais detalhes, no entanto também me parece normal. Talvez o problema ocorra em outro momento, na hora que compartilha no facebook por exemplo (o facebook compacta as imagens eu acho)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Hum, entendi! Pois é, em testes locais, também me parecia normal, mas houveram várias reclamações sobre isto, por isso pensei que o erro fosse com o html2canvas, mas tentarei sua solução, pra ver se altera algo e procurarei possíveis causas em outros trechos de código! Obrigado pela grande ajuda :) Caso eu solucione, compartilharei aqui, alterando a pergunta :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podem ser dois problemas mais conhecidos (acredito que exista um outro problema com fontes semelhante, mas parece não ser o caso):

## Problema com a tela de retina

*Tela de retina* ou *Ecrã retina* <sup>(português europeu)</sup> ou *Retina Display* <sup>(inglês)</sup> são telas usadas LCD (da Apple) que apresentam uma densidade de pixels suficiente para o olho humano não ser capaz de perceber a pixelação a uma distância padrão, usadas em produtos Apple como iPhone e Mac.

Geralmente o conteúdo exibido na tela tem em média o "dobro" de tamanho que aparenta, ou seja e geralmente temos que usar imagens de alta qualidade para que elas não apresentem o efeito desfocado ("blurry").

No momento que você usa o `html2canvas` na tela de retina, o que é lhe apresentado é uma imagem que seria apenas perceptível aos pixels. Isto parece ser um problema do `Canvas API` que tenta ajustar a imagem na hora de exporta-la.

## Bug Chrome/Safari com imagens em background no Windows 64bit

> **Nota:** Aparentemente este bug foi corrigido nas versões mais recentes do Chromium

Não me recordo se o problema ocorre no Safari, mas no Chrome e Opera (tecnologia Chromium/Blink) isto ocorre. É um bug no `Canvas API` também, que ocorre geralmente quando a imagem tem o tamanho diferente do elemento (por exemplo um DIV).

Vamos supor que temos uma imagem de 100x100 chamada *test.png* um `<div>` assim:

```
<style>
.foo {
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   background: url(test.png) no-repeat;
}
</style>
```

Se o seu Chrome for 32bit rodando em um sistema 64bit ocorre um efeito de desfoque, veja um exemplo (como eu mencionei aqui [#206](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/206)):

```js
function putImage()
{
    //Funciona-----------------------
    var canvas=document.getElementById("myCanvas1");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false; //Corrige o problema

    var pat=ctx.createPattern(img, "repeat");
    ctx.rect(0,0, 64, 64);
    ctx.fillStyle=pat;
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.restore();
    //Funciona-----------------------

    //Causa o bug-----------------------
    var canvas2=document.getElementById("myCanvas2");
    var ctx2=canvas2.getContext("2d");

    var pat=ctx2.createPattern(img, "repeat");
    ctx2.rect(0,0, 64, 64);
    ctx2.fillStyle=pat;
    ctx2.fill();

    ctx2.restore();
    //Causa o bug-----------------------
}

var img = document.getElementById("lamp");

img.onload = function() {
     setTimeout(putImage, 100);
};
```

```html
<div>
    <p>Imagem usada:</p>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvOeo.png" id="lamp">
</div>

<div style="float: left; width: 40%;">
    <p>Funciona (com ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false):</p>
    <canvas id="myCanvas1" width="300" height="318"></canvas>
</div>

<div style="float: right; width: 40%;">
    <p>Falha (se não falhar é porque está usando um navegador que já teve o bug corrigido):</p>
    <canvas id="myCanvas2" width="300" height="318"></canvas>
</div>
```

## Possível solução 1

Está solução pode funcionar com monitores Retina, mas o foco dela é resolver o problema com o `background-size`. A solução parece ocasionar algum outro problema, mas não sei ao certo qual é (talvez seja com imagens redimensionadas por `background-size` ou `width=""` e `height=""`, não tenho certeza, mas parece que o canvas perde a "precisão" das imagens redimencionadas), no entanto se a sua página é mais simples é bem possível que funcione.

No "contexto" da API do Canvas temos as propriedades:

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false; //Webkit/Safari/Chrome
ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;    //Firefox/Gecko
ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;       //Outros navegadores
```

Estas propriedades desabilitam a suavização da imagem, porém é necessário "mexer" no código fonte do `html2canvas` para conseguir aplicar isto.

## Possível solução 2

A segunda possível solução é voltada ao problema com as telas de retina, a ideia é que você pode criar uma imagem com o dobro do tamanho e reduzir ela posteriormente, o processo seria algo como:

> **Nota:** Imagens canvas muito grandes não pode ser exportadas com `.toDataURI`, pois existe um limite de tamanho.

CSS:

```
.escala-x2 {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);
       -moz-transform: scale(2);
            transform: scale(2);
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var elemento = document.getElementById("foo");

elemento.className += " escala-x2";

html2canvas(elemento).then(function(canvas) {

    elemento.className = elemento.className.replace(/\sescala\-x2/g, "");

    var new_canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

    //Copia canvas para new_canvas e redimenciona pela metade
    new_canvas.width = canvas.width / 2;
    new_canvas.height = canvas.height / 2;

    var ctx = new_canvas.getContext('2d');

    ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, new_canvas.width, new_canvas.height);
    ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false; //Webkit/Safari/Chrome
    ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;    //Firefox/Gecko
    ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;       //Outros navegadores

    canvas = null;

    document.body.appendChild(new_canvas);//Adiciona o canvas redimensionado ao body
});
```

Desta maneira você pode usar o `imageSmoothingEnabled` tranquilamente, pois as imagens originais já foram convertidas para o canvas, então é provável que não ocorra nenhum problema.

## Limite de tamanho do canvas

Cada navegador tem um limite de imagem que pode trabalhar com o Canvas, geralmente quando ultrapassar este limite é lançado um Exception, conforme a resposta do [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11585939/1518921) (estes limites vão sendo melhorados conforme o navegador recebe atualizações):

> **Nota:** Irei atualizar os dados conforme encontrar mais fontes

Dados de 10/13/2014:

- **Chrome:**

  - Máximo de largura e altura: 32,767 pixels
  - Área máxima: 268,435,456 pixels (por exemplo 16,384 x 16,384)
- **Firefox:**

  - Máximo de largura e altura: 32,767 pixels
  - Área máxima: 472,907,776 pixels (por exemplo 22,528 x 20,992)
- **Internet Explorer:**

  - Máximo de largura e altura: 8,192 pixels
- **IE Mobile:**

  - Máximo de largura e altura: 4,096 pixels

Comment: Respondi às questões que solicitou no post, sobre meu sistema operacional, etc... Irei tentar a segunda solução que você propôs, mas antes gostaria de saber qual o limite de tamanho para o uso do .toDataURI que você citou, pois as imagens que tento salvar são de tamanho: 500x450 ou 851x315. Agradeço

Comment: @ThomersonRoncally a limitação varia de navegador pra navegador, no entanto no InternetExplorer é de aproximadamente 8,192 pixels (largura e altura), vou atualizar a resposta, note que estes limites sempre são melhorados a cada atualização :) - Felizmente.

Comment: Acrescentei o código que chamo à html2canvas, é bem simples.

Comment: Poderia mostrar uma "foto" do problema? @ThomersonRoncally Pode ser o problema com o background (no entanto pode ser um novo problema) ou com as fontes.

Comment: posso sim, irei atualizar minha pergunta, tentando expôr um pouco mais meu problema